# Modificar campos de un JSON extraído de una tabla MySQL, con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

Mi problema consiste en que quiero poder acceder y modificar campos extraídos de un JSON que está insertado en un campo de una tabla en MySQL

Para ello creo una conexión y hago el select para extraer el contenido del campo de la tabla

```php
$con = new mysqli("localhost","root","","joomla_ultimate");

    if($con){
        /** Aquí filtro el select por id para simplificar, pero debe funcionar para todos los registros de la tabla (sin filtro por id) **/
        $sql = "select params from ibdes_menu where id=777";
        $query = $con->query($sql);

/** Creo un array asociativo con los datos de la tabla **/

    $data = array();
        
        while($r = $query->fetch_assoc()){
            $data[] = $r;
        }
```

Seguidamente si hago un print_r($data) podemos ver que lo que tengo es un JSON, pero en un formato que no puedo manipular con PHP

```php
    Array ( [0] => Array ( [params] => {"menu-anchor_title":"Ciudadan\u00eda","menu-anchor_css":"","menu_image":"","menu_image_css":"","menu_text":1,"menu_show":1,"page_title":"Ciudadan\u00eda","show_page_heading":"","page_heading":"","pageclass_sfx":"","menu-meta_description":"","menu-meta_keywords":"","robots":"","secure":0,"helixultimatemenulayout":"","helixultimate_enable_page_title":"0","helixultimate_page_title_alt":"","helixultimate_page_subtitle":"Informaci\u00f3n sanitaria para tener cuidado de tu salud","helixultimate_page_title_heading":"h2","helixultimate_page_title_bg_color":"","helixultimate_page_title_bg_image":"","menulayout":"{\"width\":600,\"menuItem\":1,\"menuAlign\":\"right\",\"layout\":[{\"type\":\"row\",\"attr\":[{\"type\":\"column\",\"colGrid\":12,\"menuParentId\":\"695\",\"moduleId\":\"\"}]}]}","megamenu":"0","showmenutitle":"1","icon":"","class":"","enable_page_title":"1","page_title_alt":"","page_subtitle":"Informaci\u00f3n sanitaria para tener cuidado de tu salud","page_title_bg_color":"#4dba6f","page_title_bg_image":""} ) )
```

Para poder acceder a los datos que me interesan debo hacer un json_decode  y transformarlo en un array asociativo

```php
$new_json = array();
    
    for($i = 0, $size = count($data); $i < $size; ++$i) {
        
        if (count($data[$i]) > 0) {
            /*Aquí creo un array asociativo a partir del array 'params'*/
            $datos = json_decode($data[$i]['params'], true);
        
            array_push($new_json, $datos);
            //modificamos el dato que nos interesa
            $datos['helixultimate_page_subtitle'] = $new_json[$i]['page_subtitle'];
        }
    }
```

El problema que tengo es que el JSON con la información que me interesa se encuentra ahora en la variable $datos.

Si quiero volver a codificar el JSON que extraje de la base de datos con la información modificada que ahora tengo en $datos. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

No he encontrado en ningún sitio la manera de poder hacer cambios en el JSON del campo 'params' de la base de datos y luego poder insertarlos de nuevo con los cambios que quiero.

Un saludo a todos y gracias por las respuestas.

Comment: ¿Te referís a `$data[$i]['params'] = json_encode($datos);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Después de investigar sobre este asunto he llegado a la siguiente conclusión:
el JSON al que quiero acceder es un array numérico que contiene un array asociativo (params) que a su vez contiene un objeto

`array ( [0] => array ( [params] => {"menu-anchor title":"citizen\u00eda",...`

Aquí, convierto el objeto en array asociativo para poder acceder a los datos (la $i se asigna en el bucle for del ejemplo)

`$datos = json_decode($data[$i]['params'], true);`

Si quiero volver a convertirlo en un array numérico que contenga el array "params" y a su vez que contenga un objeto debo hacer:

Convertir el array en objeto y asignarlo al array "params"
 `$datos_encode['params'] = json_encode($datos[$i]);`

asignar el objeto al array numérico

`$datos[$i] = $datos_encode;`

De esta forma obtenemos el JSON con la estructura que nos interesa para poder hacer el UPDATE a la tabla de la base de datos

`Array ( [0] => Array ( [params] => { "menu-anchor_title": "Ciudadan\u00eda",...`